# Fetch data from multiple child tables

Tags: sql

workers  | (parent table)

```
-------------------------------------------------|
name   | last name | job_id (FK) | chore_id (FK) |
-------------------------------------------------|
John   | Johnson   | 1           | 1             |
-------------------------------------------------|
Peter  | Peterson  | 2           | 2             |
-------------------------------------------------|
```

job_titles | (child table)

```
------------------------|
job_id (PK) | job_title |
------------------------|
1           | Manager   |
------------------------|
2           | Director  |
------------------------|
```

chores | (child table)

```
----------------------------|
chore_id (PK) | chore_title |
----------------------------|
1             | Clean       |
----------------------------|
2             | Dishes      |
----------------------------|
```

Above is my database.

I fetch the data from workers in PHP to display it. I want to display the job_title from the child table instead of the job_id from the parent table.

This I have achieved with:

```
SELECT name, last_name, job_title 
FROM workers, job_titles 
WHERE job_titles.job_id=workers.job_id
```

In this query I would also like to fetch the `chore_title` instead of the `chore_id`, meaning I would fetch from two child tables at once.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Add another join. BTW, you should learn how to use ANSI JOIN instead of old-style comma-separated table lists.

Comment: @Barmar I see. Any chance you can give an example on how ANSI JOIN would be used in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple joins

```
SELECT w.name, w.last_name, j.job_title, c.chore_title
FROM workers AS w
JOIN job_titles AS j ON w.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN chores AS c ON w.chore_id = c.chore_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT w.*,j.*,c.*
FROM workers w join  job_titles j on w.job_id =j.job_id 
join chores c on w.chore_id =c.chore_id  
WHERE j.job_title ='Manager'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
main.name AS name, main.last_name AS last_name, jobs_table.job_title AS job, chores_table.chore_title AS chore 
FROM workers AS main 
LEFT JOIN job_titles AS jobs_table ON main.job_id = jobs_table.job_id 
LEFT JOIN chores AS chores_table ON main.chore_id = chores.chores_id
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

With joins, you can use this

```
SELECT workers.name, workers.last_name, job_titles.job_title,chores.chore_title  
FROM workers
LEFT JOIN job_titles
ON workers.job_id = job_titles.job_id
LEFT JOIN chores
ON workers.chore_id = chores.chore_id
```

or else without join (your method)

```
SELECT workers.name, workers.last_name, job_titles.job_title, chores.chore_title
FROM workers, job_titles, chores 
WHERE workers.job_id=job_titles.job_id AND workers.chore_id = chores.chore_id
```

you can use many ways and Barmar's answer also acceptable.